# Functions on quotient topologies

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm having an issue of (seemingly) conflicting information from textbooks involving mappings between topological spaces. If $ \pi : S \rightarrow S/\sim $ is the projection of a topology S into a quotient over the relation $ \sim $, the topology of $ S $ is transferred to the quotient by requiring that all sets $ V \in S / \sim \, $ are open if $ \pi^{-1} (V) $ are open in $ S $. I'm assuming that this mapping is probably defined such that $ \pi^{-1}(V) := \{ x \in S \, | \, \pi(x) = [x] \; \;  \forall [x] \in V \subset S/\sim \}$.

In Tu's manifolds (page 72), this condition constitutes a topology because:

> $$ \pi^{-1} \Big( \bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha \Big) = \bigcup_\alpha \pi^{-1} (V_\alpha) \\
> \pi^{-1} \Big( \bigcap_\alpha V_\alpha \Big) = \bigcap_\alpha \pi^{-1} (V_\alpha) $$

for an indexed collection of sets $ V_\alpha \in S/\sim $. However, Baker's *Introduction to Topology* (page 22) states that for a mapping between sets $ f:X \rightarrow Y $ and a collection of indexed sets $ U_\alpha \in X $,

> $$ f \Big( \bigcap_\alpha U_\alpha \Big) \subseteq \bigcap_\alpha f(U_\alpha ) $$

and that equality of these two sets is satisfied *only when $ f $ is one-to-one*. However, when this is applied to the mapping $ \pi^{-1} $ above, it is not only clear that $ \pi^{-1} $ isn't one-to-one, it isn't even well defined as a function, because it's very probable that many elements of $ S $ will map to a single equivalence class in $ S/\sim $, making the inverse multi-valued. Additionally, I can't seem to find any flaw in the following proof that the missing $ \subseteq $ relationship is true all the time:

> $$ \text{Let } x \in \bigcap_\alpha \pi^{-1} (V_\alpha) \implies x \in \pi^{-1}(V_\alpha) \quad \forall \alpha \\
> \implies \exists [x] \in V_\alpha \ni \pi(x) = [x]  \quad \forall \alpha \implies [x] \in \bigcap_\alpha V_\alpha \\
> \implies x \in \pi^{-1} \Big( \bigcap_\alpha V_\alpha \Big) \implies \bigcap_\alpha \pi^{-1} (V_\alpha) \subseteq \pi^{-1} \Big( \bigcap_\alpha V_\alpha \Big) $$

So is my proof valid, and Baker is simply wrong? I highly doubt that, it seems I'm missing something critical on why Tu is still correct, and Baker's theorem doesn't apply to this situation? I've seen a similar proof to the above posted here before, **I guess my main question is why Baker's one-to-one restriction on the equality isn't killing my proof and as a result Tu's definition.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a function $\phi : A \to B$ between two sets $A,B$, then we can define for each subset $M \subset A$ its image
$$\phi(M) = \{ \phi(a) \mid a \in M \} \subset B$$
and for each subset $N \subset B$ its preimage
$$\phi^{-1}(N) = \{ a \in A \mid \phi(a) \in N \} \subset A.$$
**$\phi^{-1}$ is not a function from $B$ to $A$.** It is actually a function
$$\phi^{-1} : \mathfrak P (B) \to \mathfrak P (A), $$
where $\mathfrak P (X)$ denotes the *powerset* of the set $X$. Alternatively we could interpret $\phi^{-1}$ as "multivalued function from $B$ to $A$".  Note that for a *bijection* $\phi : A \to B$ one usually writes $\phi^{-1} : B \to A$ for the inverse function. Thus we have the same notation for two different things:

1. $\phi^{-1} : \mathfrak P (B) \to \mathfrak P (A)$ which is defined for *all functions $\phi : A \to B$*
2. $\phi^{-1} : B \to A$ which is defined only *for bijections $\phi : A \to B$*

This may be confusing, but if you are used to it you will not regard it as a problem. The interpretation of $\phi^{-1}$ is normally clear from the context.

Similarly one writes
$$\phi : \mathfrak P (A) \to \mathfrak P (B)$$
for the "image function" determined by $\phi$ which is also a little ambiguous.

Concerning unions the functions $\phi : \mathfrak P (A) \to \mathfrak P (B)$ and $\phi^{-1} : \mathfrak P (B) \to \mathfrak P (A)$ have the same behavior:
$$\phi(\bigcup_\alpha M_\alpha) = \bigcup_\alpha \phi(M_\alpha) \phantom{x}, \phantom{x} \phi^{-1}(\bigcup_\alpha N_\alpha) = \bigcup_\alpha \phi^{-1}(N_\alpha)  .$$
However, concerning intersections their behavior is different:
$$\phi(\bigcap_\alpha M_\alpha) \subset \bigcap_\alpha \phi(M_\alpha) \text{ but in general } \phi(\bigcap_\alpha M_\alpha) \ne \bigcap_\alpha \phi(M_\alpha)  \phantom{x}, \phantom{x} \phi^{-1}(\bigcap_\alpha N_\alpha) = \bigcap_\alpha \phi^{-1}(N_\alpha) .$$
Baker is right,  the injectivity of $\phi : A \to B$ is a *necessary and sufficent* condition for
$$(*) \phantom x \phi(\bigcap_\alpha M_\alpha) = \bigcap_\alpha \phi(M_\alpha). $$
To see that it is necessary, consider a non-injective function $\phi :A \to B$. There are $a, a' \in A$ such that $a \ne a'$ and $\phi(a) = \phi(a') = b$. Then $\emptyset = \phi(\emptyset) = \phi(\{a\} \cap \{a'\}) \ne \{b\} = \phi(\{a\}) \cap \phi(\{a'\})$. To see that it is sufficient, let $b \in  \bigcap_\alpha \phi(M_\alpha)$, i.e. $b \in \phi(M_\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$. Thus $b = \phi(a_\alpha)$ for suitable $a_\alpha \in M_\alpha$. But since $\phi$ is injective we must have $a_\alpha = a_{\alpha'}$ for all $\alpha,\alpha'$. This means $a_\alpha = a$ for all $\alpha$. Clearly $a \in \bigcap_\alpha M_\alpha$, thus $b \in \phi(\bigcap_\alpha M_\alpha)$.

Your proof for $\phi^{-1}$ is correct and you do not need the *injectivity* of $\phi : A \to B$. But there is no contradiction: It only means that different functions (like $\phi : \mathfrak P (A) \to \mathfrak P (B)$ and $\phi^{-1} : \mathfrak P (B) \to \mathfrak P (A)$) may behave in a different manner.

Comment: I corrected my answer, the claim about constant functions was nonsense.

Comment: The distinction between definitions 1. and 2. clarify the situation for me greatly, thank you. The concept of pre-image is now perfectly clear, I'm just embarrassed that I somehow have avoided true understanding of the concept until now.

Answer (score 1):

Preimages of maps behave differently, in some sense "nicer" if you want, than images. One of my professors always used to say

> preimages are good, images are evil.

What he meant is that, given a map $f\colon X\to Y$ with a collection of subsets $A_i \subset X, B_i \subset Y$ for an index set $I$, **preimages** respect unions and intersections $$f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_i B_i\right) = \bigcap_if^{-1}(B_i)\quad \text{and}\quad f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_i B_i\right) = \bigcup_if^{-1}(B_i)$$
the **images**, in general, do not:

$$f\left(\bigcap_i A_i\right) \subseteq \bigcap_i f(A_i)$$

And, as you already figured, they are equal iff $f$ is injective.

However, you still seem to be confusing a few things. The projection $\pi$ is for obvious reasons not injective but it's surjective and it's certainly well defined. You are confusing preimages $$\pi^{-1}([s])\subset S$$ of elements $[s]\in S/{\sim}$ under $\pi$, which are subsets of $S$, with the inverse function $$\pi^{-1}\colon S/{\sim}\to S.$$ These are entirely different things.

The projection $\pi$ projects all elements $a,a' \in S$ that are equal $a\sim a'$ *with respect to the equivalence relation* $\sim$ onto their common equivalence class $[a]$ in $S/{\sim}$.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to imply that $ \pi^{-1} $ isn't well-defined as a single-valued function, not $ \pi $. I think I see now, though, thank you!