# How to understand Urysohn’s lemma?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying general topology. And I have problem in understanding Urysohn's lemma.

Urysohn's Lemma : If $X$ is normal and $C$, $D$ are disjoint subsets of $X$, there exists continuous map $f$ : $X \rightarrow [0, 1]$  s.t. $f(C)=0$, $f(D)=1$.

How can $f$ be defined  like that? For example, if $X=R$, $C=[0, 1]$, $D=[2, 3]$, how can we define such $f$?

$f([0, 1])$ and $f([2, 3])$ can be defined on the 'set of subsets of $R$', not on $R$.

'$f$ defined on $R$' means $f(x)$, where $x$ is a real number. Not the interval.

How can I understand it? Is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: $f(C)=\{f(x):x\in C\}$. We want the *restriction* of $f$ to be the constant $0$ map.

Comment: More explicitely it just means that $f$ is identically $0$ on $C$ and $1$ on $D$

Comment: Perhaps my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3932514 is helpful to clarify things.

Comment: Ah, there was very huge misunderstanding! Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ and $S$ is a subset of $A$, then$$f(S)=\{f(s)\mid s\in S\}.$$

So, the statement of Urysohn's Lemma actually is:

> If $X$ is normal and $C$ and $D$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$, then there exists a continuous map $f\colon X\longrightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(C)=\{0\}$ and that $f(D)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Ah, so $f(C)=0$ means 'every element of $C$ has value 0'. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @random487510: It is a very common abuse of notation — an abuse because the lefthand side is a **subset** of $[0,1]$, while the righthand side is an **element** of $[0,1]$ and really ought to be $\{0\}$, as in the answer.

Comment: @rschwieb Right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.